# Warning when adding Link to a Page (using page manager), Why?

Tags: routes, chaos-tool-suite

I am using Drupal 7. 
I created a page using page manager. 
In the "Basic" tab I gave it a path  (didn't make it my home page): 'abcpath/all'
In the "Menu"  tab I chose "No menu entry.

then I want to structure -> Menus -> add new menu, and created new menu.
In this menu I created new link, using the same path ('abcpath/all').

Now, when I am going back to the page in page manager, to the "Content" tab, I see the following warning:

Warning: strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in drupal_validate_utf8() (line 1587 of D:\MYSITE\includes\bootstrap.inc). 
Notice: Array to string conversion in filter_xss() (line 1442 of D:\MYSITE\includes\common.inc).
Notice: Array to string conversion in filter_xss() (line 1442 of D:\MYSITE\includes\common.inc).
Notice: Array to string conversion in filter_xss() (line 1442 of D:\MYSITE\includes\common.inc).
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in drupal_render() (line 5886 of D:\MYSITE\includes\common.inc).

I checked it few times and it's always happen and defiantly because of the link.

can somebody please help here?

Thanks!

Comment: It is a bug in core, where an array is passed as an argument to a function that expects a string argument.

Comment: OK, thanks. 
It does not effect performance? Can I fix it?